# how to test whether a potential gives rise to a force field

Tags: forces, potential

**A preamble** to my problem.

I have measured a discrete vector field, $\vec{F}(x,y) = (F_x(x,y), F_y(x,y))$ representing some forces i'm currently researching. $\vec{F}$ is the average of forces acting onto trajectories in the neighborhood of a certain point $(x,y)$ in space. I also have measured a quantity that is a discrete scalar field $\phi(x,y)$, and is the average of some other quantity per trajectory in the neghborhood of $(x,y)$. For all our purposes, $x,y \in {1,2,3...}$, meaning the coordinate values of my samples are discrete and regularly spaced, so with the right transformation they might as well be rotated onto natural numbers.

**Hypothesis:** I strongly suspect that the field is acting as a potential generating the vector field, i.e.
$$
-\vec{\nabla} \phi(x,y) = \vec{F}(x,y)
$$
 and I set out to quantitatively prove it. (After that I'll try to understand why is it so, if it's the case).

**First thing** I did, quick and dirty, was to look for correlations between respective components of the gradient and of the vector field, i.e. I tested whether
$$
-\vec{\nabla}_i \phi(x,y) \propto \vec{F}_i(x,y) \qquad for \quad i \in {x,y}
$$
and i got a nice linear relation with pearson's $R^2 \approx 0.8$ on the y axis, but a much less clear relation on the x axis, with $R^2 \approx 0.4$.

**Next thing** I did was to look at the scalar products versus the squared module of the velocity field. the test was:
$$
-\vec{\nabla} \phi(x,y) \cdot \vec{F}(x,y) \propto \vec{F}^2(x,y) \qquad \forall {x,y}
$$
A linear model responded well, with $R^2 \approx 0.9$, and there were no negative values among the scalar products, but the data does seem to systematically stray away from a line for the five highest values.

**My problem is:** are there more refined tests to check the validity of my hypothesis? I've been looking for numerical tests for differential equations, but didn't find much. Are there any? Even better, is there any tried and true technique to test the validity of a potential respect to a dynamics? Some hours of search yielded nothing (but it's probably because I'm not very experienced in dynamical systems theory).

Sorry if I did something wrong in composing the question, it's my first time on StackExchange. If you point me to any errors I'll be pleased to correct them. And thanks in advance for any help you might give me!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there are tests that can show whether a force field is a gradient of a unknown scalar field. If it isn't the gradient of a scalar field then it definitely isn't proportional to the gradient of that particular scalar field.

The test alluded to above is whether the circulation around every closed loop is zero. So if you can find the work done around a closed loop and it is definitely nonzero, that's your evidence right there.

And if it is then you can construct a scalar field by finding the change in scalar field due to work done by the force field along a path from a fixed point.

Now you can have a single offset and a single scaling factor to see if the potential the field makes is proportional to a shifted version of the scalar field you started with.  If the best fit one minus the scalar field you started with is definitely nonzero then they are different.